# Static files in tests

Tags: testing, go

When I write tests in Go that require static files (for example a file `hello.txt` where I test my program that `hello.txt` is read correctly), where should I place the static files? How should I address them in the test file?

That is, currently my setup is a local directory, `GOPATH` is set to this directory. There I have

```
src/
   mypkg/
        myfile.go
        myfile_test.go
testfiles/
          hello.txt
          world.txt
```

Now in `myfile_test.go`, I don't want to use an absolute path to refer to `testfiles/hello.txt`. Is there any idiomatic way to do that?

Is this a sensible layout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common approach is to have, for example

```
$GOPATH/src/
        mypkg/
                myfile.go
                myfile_test.go
                _testdata/
                        hello.txt
                        world.txt
```

Then, in your foo_test, use

```
f, err := os.Open("_testdata/hello.txt")
....
```

or

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("_testdata/hello.txt")
....
```

The testing package makes sure that the CWD is `$GOPATH/src/mypkg` when the test binary executes.

Comment: The more I learn Go, the more I see how much thought has been put into it.